# Delete rows based on values of two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retain any rows in excel which only contain "ECGS2A" or "ECGS2B" in column E and "Customer Opt In" in column M but having difficulty with trying different VBA codes.

I need to retain headers on row 4 but when trying to add range other than column E on:

```
j = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

I get an error or "Run time error '1004': Method of 'Range' of object_Global' failed

```
' Deleting entire rows with MyTarget
Sub myDeleteRows2()

Const MyTarget = "*ECGS2A*"

Dim Rng As Range, DelCol As New Collection, x
Dim I As Long, j As Long, k As Long

' Calc last row number
j = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Collect rows range with MyTarget
For I = 1 To j
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(I), MyTarget) = 0 Then 'changed from > 0
k = k + 1
If k = 1 Then
Set Rng = Rows(I)
Else
Set Rng = Union(Rng, Rows(I))
If k >= 100 Then
DelCol.Add Rng
k = 0
End If
End If
End If
Next
If k > 0 Then DelCol.Add Rng

' Turn off screen updating and events
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Delete rows with MyTarget
For Each x In DelCol
x.Delete
Next


' Update UsedRange
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange: End With

' Restore screen updating and events
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

also tried

```
Sub DeleteRowsBasedOnMultipleCriteria()

lRow = 13 ' Your last row with the data

Do While lRow >= 1

'1=Column A,6=Column F, 18=Column R
 If Cells(lRow, 5) = "ECGS9" _
        Or Cells(lRow, 13) = "Customer Opt Out" Then
        Rows(lRow).Delete
 End If

lRow = lRow - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I expect to be left with column E only displaying anything with ECGS2A or ECGS2B and column M as Customer Opt In.  If the columns display anything other than those mentioned, I want them deleted.

[image]

Comment: you mentioned you have headers on row 4, so is the data from row 5 downwards?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'd also rather not use "ECGS9" in the code and instead have a code that only looks for anything other than "ECGS2A" or "ECGS2B" and deletes it.

Comment: OK try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161093/5166387) below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
    LRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LRow To 5 Step -1
        If Not ((.Cells(i,5) Like "ECGS2A*" Or .Cells(i,5) Like "ECGS2B*") And .Cells(i, 13) Like "Customer Opt In*")  Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The headers remain but all of the data gets deleted even though there are cells containing the values I mentioned.

Comment: Still deleting everything.  Not sure if I was specific but there is text after the ECGS2A or B in my report (i.e."ECGS2A Mr Smith", so I want the code to just read the beginning of the text in Column E, rather than delete  if it *only* doesn't say ECGS2A/B

Comment: @rwc14, Oh, you should have mentioned this.... I have updated the answer to use the `Like` operator. It would work now.

Comment: Hyperlinked above as can't embed yet. Thanks.

Comment: Smashing.  Thanks very much :-) Works perfectly.